# Problems with Ultrasonic Sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, wires

I want to check my understanding on how to use `digitalWrite` for `5V` and `Grd` and why this code isn't working.

This is for the [Makeblock sensor](http://learn.makeblock.com/en/me-ultrasonic-sensor/)

Consider [the image here](http://learn.makeblock.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/%E5%BE%AE%E4%BF%A1%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE_20160129144228.png) which says to plugin a wire to 5V, Grd and a signal pin.

My code does the following

```
#define h  22
#define l  24
#define sig 26

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinModde(h, OUTPUT);
   pindMode(l, OUPUT);
   pinMode(sig, OUPUT);
   
   digitalWrite(h, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(l, LOW);
}

void loop() {
   digitalWrite(sig, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(2);
   digitalWrite(sig, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(10);
   digitalWrite(sig, LOW);
   pinMode(sig, INPUT);
   long duration = pulseIn(sig, HIGH, 38000);
   delay(2500);
}
```

When I run this code duration is always `0`.  If I unplug `22` and `24` and use the board's `5V` and `Grd` I get duration is `30001` no matter how far away an object is from the sensor.  Meaning it's not sensing anything, just returning this number.

Full disclosure that I'm using solder-less wires but I don't that would make this much of a difference?

So to summarize: why are 22 and 24 resulting in a 0 readout and not acting as 5V and Grd?  My only thought is maybe too much voltage and a resister is needed?

Secondly: why is the sensor not working even when using 5V and Grd pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `pinMode(sig,INPUT);` and never changed this back to `OUTPUT` before triggering next measure:

```
void loop() {
   pinMode(sig, OUTPUT);    // ensure sig is configured as an output
   digitalWrite(sig, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(2);
   digitalWrite(sig, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(10);
   digitalWrite(sig, LOW);
   pinMode(sig, INPUT);
   long duration = pulseIn(sig, HIGH, 38000);
   delay(2500);
}
```

And for example PING))) (which is basically the same module) has power consumption about 30mA-35mA in datasheet. Output pin might be strong enough to power it, but I'd recommend at least GND connect directly to arduino GND. And using transistor for powering it up would be even better